# Using Fragments in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to use fragments in my application, but something is wrong with them. The application doesn't even show anything. It starts and immediately shuts down.

my mainActivity class:

```
package com.fintechflow.client;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

my main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

sample of one fragment:

```
package com.fintechflow.client;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.fintechflow.client.databinding.MainFragmentBinding;


public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

    private MainFragmentBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = MainFragmentBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        binding.button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_homeFragment);
        });

        binding.signUpHyperlink.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_registerFragment);
        });
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".FragmentMain">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="324dp"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_logo_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_user_icon"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/username_hint"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_input"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/custom_password_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="12dp"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_button"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_sign_in_activity"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.063"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_up_hyperlink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_up_hyperlink"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my_nav.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.fintechflow.client.FragmentMain"
        android:label="fragment_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:name="com.fintechflow.client.FragmentRegister"
        android:label="fragment_register"
        tools:layout="@layout/register_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registerFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.fintechflow.client.FragmentHome"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I searched for documentation and this code seems fine, but the app is not even loading.
Should I use FragmentManager in mainActivity.java place them all there?

Comment: You're using `app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"`, which means the `res/navigation/my_nav.xml` file is the one controlling which screens show up in the NavHostFragment. Can you include that file here?

Comment: have you specified `startDestination` in `@navigation/my_nav` nav graph?

Comment: ok, I added my_nav.xml to the post down below.

Comment: can you please provide the error logs ? So that it can help better understand the problem

Comment: There is no errors.